# Is the article Generic<Programming> Typed Buffers completely obsolete with C++ 11?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I am reading [Generic<Programming> Typed Buffers](http://www.drdobbs.com/generictyped-buffers-i/184403791), a pretty old article from Andrei Alexandrescu.

I'm wondering if it still makes sense.  In his article Alexandrescu points out some issues with `std::vector` when performance is critical:

- Unnecessary data initialization when allocating a vector which I think can be solved using `std::vector::reserve`
- expensive move operation which is solved with C++11 and move semantics
- most compiler do not optimize `std::vector` for type such as `char` by using `std::memcpy` and `std::memmove`. This is untrue now for mainstream compilers (from what I have seen).
- Exponential growth. You can not shrink the capacity of the `std::vector` to fit the size with a simple method call. Which is also untrue since C++11 with `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()`

My question is, is this article completely obsolete, can I now rely on vector (including custom allocator if necessary) to have a fast contiguous buffer?

Comment: The last point is not correct: `shrink_to_fit` can only shrink by copying the data to a new, smaller block.

Comment: First point, do you mean initialization or allocation?

Comment: Thanks i will edit the question, i meant that shrink_to_fit is integrated and the _user_ must not do unnecessary copies of course internally copies are made

Comment: I mean initialization, the items constructors are called which can be expensive when using resize, not when using reserve. This can be unnecessary in certain situation.

Comment: You can't use `reserve` and then pass the data to a C function (which is what the article is talking about regarding initialization). You'd have to call `resize`, which would indeed initialize the data.

Comment: @interjay You said you can not use `reserve` and then pass it to a C function, i don't understand why.

Comment: @juanchopanza cannot `shrink_to_fit` use move semantics for vectors of objects, instead of copying? (assuming a move ctor exists) Of course it still has to allocate `O(N)` pointers and preform `O(N)` moves.

Comment: @vsoftco Sure it can, but this only helps if the objects are cheaply movable. `shrink_to_fit` doesn't do anything that cannot be done using other functions (except that it can chose to do nothing, and it often does.)

Comment: @juanchopanza It's possible for `shrink_to_fit` to use knowledge of the allocator internals to do something other than copying the data to a new block. For example, if the allocator uses `malloc`/`free` to obtain memory blocks `shrink_to_fit` can be implemented with `realloc` if either (a) the type `is_trivially_move_constructible` or (b) the `realloc` implementation is known to never relocate in memory when asked to shrink a block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++11 largely closes the gap between `std::vector` and raw arrays (move semantics and `shrink_to_fit` solve some of Alexandrescu's points), but the niche still exists to some extent; `std::vector` continues to value-initialize elements; `reserve` doesn't help because you can't access the reserved memory. You can hack around this with a custom allocator, but it's far from satisfactory.

From the other end, `unique_ptr<T[]>` makes holding a buffer in your container class much more straightforward as it largely solves exception-safety issues. The TS [`dynarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray), which offers fixed-size allocation at construction with default-initialization, looks likely to close much of the remainder of the gap.

The remaining niche that Alexandrescu's generic buffers occupy is to offer default-initialized elements with O(n) shrink and grow operations; these are generally not useful as a component of container classes and if required can be written as non-member functions.

Comment: I don't understand why you say it is not possible to access the reserved memory. I tried to use `reserve()`and then `data()`, and then copy this data to an allocated `int*` using `memcpy`and it seemed to work. I think i am missing something

Comment: @vac “it seems to work” is an irrelevant observation when it comes to [undefined behaviour](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).